# How to internationalize accelerator of JMenuitem?

Tags: java, swing, locale

I use jdk 1.6 and i'd like to internationalize the accelerator of my menu item.
the default language is french and i want to translate in english. I use the code below :

```
JMenuItem deleteMenuItem = new JMenuItem("delete");
deleteMenuItem.setLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
deleteMenuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE,0));
```

but my accelerator is always in french.
How can I resolve this ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the Default-locale for your application. Then it will work.

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: Try to do the `setDefaultLocale()` call before the Frame is constructed. At best right in your `main()` method

Answer (score 0):

For internationalized accelerator to English, you need to call `Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH)` before instantiate new JFrame. Below sample I change France language in accelerator.My machine locale is English.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.FRANCE);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("MenuSample Example");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

    JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
    fileMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
    menuBar.add(fileMenu);

    JMenuItem newMenuItem = new JMenuItem("New", KeyEvent.VK_N);
    fileMenu.add(newMenuItem);


    JMenuItem cutMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Cut", KeyEvent.VK_T);

    KeyStroke ctrlXKeyStroke = KeyStroke
            .getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_CUT, 0);

    cutMenuItem.setAccelerator(ctrlXKeyStroke);

    fileMenu.add(cutMenuItem);

    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    frame.setSize(350, 250);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

The output is

[image]

Comment: thanks @Sai Ye Yan Naing Aye I'have wrote "delete" because I wanted to be explicit,it is just for the question,in my real code i have use ResourceBundle. The problem i have is to translate the accelerator of my menu item.